# Country-Specific EULAs for Android

Tags: android, eula

The Android app EULA has to be part of the app and is generated using the eula class. It appears to be USA specific. Is there a way to automatically generate country-specific EULAs in Android?

On the iPhone, iTunes does this automatically.

Has anyone had any experience in this area?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to automatically generate country-specific EULAs in Android?

Only if you can embed an attorney into an Android phone.

You can *display* country-specific EULAs in Android by using the mobile country code (MCC) in the resource sets. So, you might have the US EULA in `res/raw/eula.txt` and the UK EULA in `res/raw-mcc234/eula.txt`. For more on the resource set construct, see [Table 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). To find the MCC for a country, visit [this page](https://www.numberingplans.com/?page=plans&sub=imsinr).

Comment: Upvoted purely for the "embed an attorney" observation. "Generate." Hehe. ;)